# Blocking access based on reverse hostname lookup

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I've got some joker trying to subscribe a bunch of email addresses to my mailman system and I want to block him from accessing the apache web server.

According to the apache log, he's accessing from a very consistent hostname ... variations on x12356.example.com.br (where the numbers changed).

The problem is, the actual hostname that's appearing in the log doesn't resolve ... but, once I was able to get the IP (by turning off hostname resolution), I found that the IP did resolve on a reverse IP lookup.

I tried the following in my htaccess file, but it's not blocking.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ".*\.example\.com\.br"
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I also tried a simple 'Deny from', but it's not blocking either.

```
Deny from .example.com.br
```

My gut says I'm missing something simple, but I can't see it.

Here's the complete .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.l\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://lists.mydomain.com/listinfo/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mailbait [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mailbait.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /mailbait.php [L]

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(testproxy|upload|xmlrpc|wp|blog|wordpress)" spammer=yes

RewriteCond %{ENV:spammer} ^yes$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tarpit.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /tarpit.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ".*\.example\.com\.br"
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
Deny from .example.com.br
```

Comment: Show your `.htaccess` file, maybe the ordering is wrong. Your second example _should_ work, IMO. Edit: or just use `iptables` / any other firewall to drop the connection

Comment: I updated the post with the .htaccess file

Comment: Try `Order Allow,Deny
Deny from .example.com.br
Allow from all` before your rewrite rules

Comment: Sadly, no change. :(

Comment: Ah wait, you said it's always the same IP? Why don't you block that? Same notation `Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and drop your rewrite rule for `.example.com.br`

Comment: No, the IP changes ... along with the full reverse hostname.  The only thing that is consistent is the last 3 segments of the hostname that is appearing in the log.  The hostname in the log doesn't actually resolve ... but the IP resolves to the hostname in the log on a reverse IP lookup.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a bit slow today...Apache always uses reverse DNS lookups to resolve `deny` directives, I think. So maybe that's why it doesn't work. I gotta go now, so maybe have a look at [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Apache)